# How to insert many records in Realm with Swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to perform a massive insertion of data in Realm, but it is making it very slow.

This is my code:

```
let realm = try! Realm()


let group = GroupRealm()

group.id = 1
group.name = "test"

try! realm.write { 
    realm.add(group)
}

var product = [String:AnyObject]()
product["id"] = "" as AnyObject!
product["code"] = ("") as AnyObject!
product["detail"] = ("") as AnyObject!
product["onHand"] = (0) as AnyObject!
product["price"] = (0) as AnyObject!
product["isSerialized"] = (0) as AnyObject!
product["isLotNumber"] = (0) as AnyObject!

var groupProduct = [String:AnyObject]()
groupProduct["group"] = group as AnyObject!

for r in 0..<300 {
    realm.beginWrite()
    for i in 0..<100 {
        product["id"] = "\(i)-\(r)" as AnyObject!
        realm.create(ProductRealm.self, value: product, update: true)

        groupProduct["id"] = "\(i)-\(r)" as AnyObject!
        groupProduct["product"] = product as AnyObject!
        realm.create(GroupProductRealm.self, value: groupProduct, update: true)
    }
    try! realm.commitWrite()
}
```

Objects:

```
class ProductRealm: Object {
    public dynamic var id: String = ""
    public dynamic var code: String = ""
    public dynamic var detail: String = ""
    public dynamic var onHand: Int = 0
    public dynamic var price: Double = 0
    public dynamic var isSerialized: Int = 0
    public dynamic var isLotNumber: Int = 0
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class GroupProductRealm: Object {
    public dynamic var id = ""
    public dynamic var group: GroupRealm!
    public dynamic var product: ProductRealm!
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
class GroupRealm: Object {
    public dynamic var id = 1
    public dynamic var name = ""
    public dynamic var update = Date()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

The tests on my iphone 5s to insert 30000 records are delayed for more than 30 seconds, whereas in an old project I have with sqlite it takes about 16 seconds.

I have read that realm is much faster in this than sqlite so I know it is an error of mine, but I do not give with the D:

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Why are you doing the writes in separate 300 write transactions rather than in a single write transaction?

Comment: I have a code to display a counter every time you insert 100 records, and check the times with and without that part of the code and it does not influence much

Comment: Test with the 30000 in single transaction.
Time: 25 seconds

Comment: How are you integrating Realm into your test app? CocoaPods, Carthage, or the prebuilt binaries that Realm provides?

Comment: Binary, Which is better?

Comment: It's up to your preference. I ask because if you were building Realm from source (via CocoaPods, for instance) you'd want to make sure to build the Release configuration rather than Debug, otherwise Realm itself would be built without optimizations. For what it's worth, I dropped the code you provided into one of Xcode's iOS app templates and ran it on my iPhone 7 Plus. The insertions took ~5.5 seconds. Can you share the code you're using to test SQLite so I can compare on the same iPhone?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, already manage to reduce the time enough, with the use of a json and correcting the relations between objects.

Answer (score 0):

My level of English is not very high, so I will publish the code with the comments in Spanish, if someone can modify it to be in English I would appreciate it.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48676/como-insertar-muchos-registros-en-realm-con-swift/48913#48913

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TestRealm
//
//  Created by Sergio Castro on 10/02/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 BasTechSoluctions. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Mostrar la ubicación del proyecto para ubicar la base de datos
        print(FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.absoluteString)


        DispatchQueue(label: "background").async { //Abrir un nuevo hilo para insertar de forma asíncrona
            autoreleasepool {

                let date1 = Date() // Inicia el conteo del tiempo

                let realm = try! Realm() // Instanciar realm en el hilo nuevo

                let products = realm.objects(ProductRealm.self) //Crear una lista de todos los productos

                //Crear grupo
                let group = GroupRealm()
                group.id = 1
                group.name = "test"

                try! realm.write { //Insertar/Reemplazar grupo, sin productos
                    realm.create(GroupRealm.self, value: group, update: true)
                }

                ///Crear json
                //Primero creo un String, donde ingreso todos los datos en formato [{},{},...]
                var stringJson = "["
                for i in 0..<30000 {
                    if(i > 0){ stringJson.append(",") }
                    let dataOrigin = "{\"id\": \"\(i)\", \"code\": \"\", \"detail\": \"\", \"onHand\": 0, \"price\": 0, \"isSerialized\": 0, \"isLotNumber\": 0}"
                    stringJson.append("\(dataOrigin)")
                }
                stringJson.append("]")

                //Convertir el String en Datos y luego pasarlo a jsonObject (esto para simular el proceso de descarga de datos)
                let data = stringJson.data(using: .utf8)!
                let jsonP = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [Any]

                //Mostrar el tiempo empleado para la creación del json en consola, el tiempo está en segundos por defecto
                let date2 = Date()
                var time = date2.timeIntervalSince(date1)
                print("Json creation in seconds \(time)")

                //Recorrer el json en grupos de 100, tantas veces haga falta para recorrer por completo el json, en este caso 300 veces
                let limit = 100
                for c in 0..<(jsonP.count / limit){
                    //Insertar/Reemplazar los grupos de datos
                    realm.beginWrite()
                    for i in 0..<limit{
                        let row = jsonP[i + (c*limit)]
                        realm.create(ProductRealm.self, value: row, update: true)
                    }
                    try! realm.commitWrite()
                    //Mostrar en consola la cantidad de procesos realizados vs la cantidad de registros actuales
                    ///print("\((c+1)*limit) / \(products.count)") //Este proceso aumenta el tiempo de cálculo
                    print("\((c+1)*limit)") //Este proceso no afecta mucho el tiempo de cálculo
                }

                group.products.append(objectsIn: products) //Agregar los productos al grupo, aquí se pueden poner filtros

                //Actualizar el grupo, para que el array products tenga una referencia a sus productos correspondientes
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.create(GroupRealm.self, value: group, update: true)
                }

                // Calcular el tiempo de inserción y mostrarlo en consola
                let date3 = Date()
                time = date3.timeIntervalSince(date2)
                print("Finish time in seconds \(time)")

            }
        }
    }
}


class ProductRealm: Object {
    public dynamic var id: String = ""
    public dynamic var code: String = ""
    public dynamic var detail: String = ""
    public dynamic var onHand: Int = 0
    public dynamic var price: Double = 0
    public dynamic var isSerialized: Int = 0
    public dynamic var isLotNumber: Int = 0
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class GroupRealm: Object {
    public dynamic var id = 1
    public dynamic var name = ""
    public dynamic var update = Date()
    let products = List<ProductRealm>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```